# Updating attributes of one model from a different model's controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a simple post and user app where users submit and upvote posts. I have two models, post and user, and right now I'm working with the post model to add "upvoting" functionality.

Each post has an `:id`, `:upvote` and `:users_voted_by` attribute.
Each user has a `:username`, `:posts_voted_on` and `good_karma` attribute

When a user clicks the upvote button on a post, I need to make sure the current user isn't in the `:users_voted_by` column for that post, if not, add 1 to the `:upvote` attribute of that post. This part is done.

But I also need to add the post `:id` into the current user's `:posts_voted_on` field and add 1 to the submitter's `:good_karma` field.

## Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_count, :downvote, :id, :text, :title, :upvote, :url, :user, :users_voted_by
end
```

## User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username, :posts_voted_on, :good_karma, :bad_karma

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

## My upvote method is within posts_controller:

```
  def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.users_voted_by.index(current_user.username) == nil && @post.update_attributes(:upvote => @post.upvote + 1, :users_voted_by => @post.users_voted_by + ',' + current_user.username)
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The 5th line is where the magic is. Is makes sure the post I'm voting on doesn't have the current user in the `:users_voted_by` field. Then it updates the `:upvote` and `:users_voted_by` fields.

**How can I add to this method (action?) so that it also updates the attributes of the voting user and the post submitter to store the increase in karma.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess a [service object](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) can help here, something like (not tested)

```
class Voter
  def initialize(post, user)
    @post = post
    @user = user
  end

  def upvote
    return false unless @post.users_voted_by.index(@user.username)
    @post.upvote += 1
    @post.users_voted_by = @post.users_voted_by + ',' + @user.username
    @user.good_carma += 1
    @post.save && @user.save
  end

  def downvote
    ...
  end
end
```

Then controller will look like

```
   def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if Voter.new(@post, current_user).upvote
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where does the service object go?

Comment: `app/services/voter.rb`. `services` folder does not exist by default, just create it. Actually, you can name it as you wish.

Comment: How do I include it into my app? Must I do anything additional to get the Voter class to work?

Comment: Nothing to do, just create folder/file.

Comment: Sweet! How can I store the array of users who have upvoted a post. Someone recommended serialization. Any clues?

Comment: It's a quite standard approach. Check the docs for details and examples http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22502/discussion-between-jackson-gariety-and-dimuch)